# Where Can I Find List<T>.AddRange() Method?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, generic-list

I have some old school looking code that is as follows:

```
IList<KeyValuePair<string, ValuePair>> ServicePairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ValuePair>>();
// ...
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> Set in Services)
{
    if (string.Format("{0} (Service)", Set.Value) == c.ColumnName)
    {
        ServicePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, ValuePair>(c.Ordinal.ToString(), new ValuePair { Id = Set.Key, Title = Set.Value }));
    }
}
```

Resharper is suggesting I pretty it up a bit by converting it to the following:

```
ServicePairs.AddRange(from Set in Services
                      where string.Format("{0} (Service)", Set.Value) == c.ColumnName
                      select new KeyValuePair<string, ValuePair>(
                          c.Ordinal.ToString(),
                          new ValuePair { Id = Set.Key, Title = Set.Value }));
```

What I'd like to know is - where does this `AddRange()` method come from - is it from [Microsoft Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) or somewhere else?

**UPDATE:** It's been pointed out that this is part of the `List<T>` class.  Apparently, it's not part of the `IList<T>` interface, which was the source of my confusion.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [a method of the `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I believe you were the first to respond.

Answer (score 3):

Its part of [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) which is part of the BCL.

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` in `System.Collections.Generic` iirc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find out in VS if you right click on AddRange and select "Go To Definition"

You'll see some variation of this at the top of the Class

```
#region Assembly mscorlib.dll, v4.0.30319
// C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll
#endregion
```

Comment: In my scenario, the problem was the compiler didn't know what AddRange() was.  See my update on the question for more information.